# Tamanho de conteúdo de uma variável vinda de uma requisição

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-request

Tenho uma aplicação web desenvolvida em Laravel 5.0, a qual recebe uma requisição via POST de uma outra aplicação. Os dados enviados é um JSON com uma quantidade relativamente grande de informações, e quando eu obtenho esta requisição e acesso os dados via `Request::all()` dependendo do tamanho eu estou perdendo parte dos dados.

Fizemos um teste pegando estes dados via `file_get_contents()`, ou seja, PHP nativo e percebemos que os dados chegam completos.

Inicialmente acreditamos que tenha alguma configuração no PHP.INI referente ao tamanho que uma variável pode aceitar.

Gostaria de saber se estou no caminho certo ou se já passaram por essa situação e como foi resolvida.

Comment: Talvez isto possa ajudá-lo. https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars Ou, defina um valor maior para max_input_vars no **php.ini**